# PHP MYSQL search based on rating and timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, rating-system

My search query runs like:

```
 select * from posts p where p.post like '%test%' ORDER BY p.upvotes DESC, 
 p.unix_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20
```

If there are more than 20 results for the searched keyword, i find out the minimum timestamp value, store it in a hidden element and run another query to Load More results like:

```
select * from posts p where p.post like '%test%' and p.unix_timestamp < 1360662045
ORDER BY p.upvotes DESC, p.unix_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20
```

Whats really happening is that my first query is ignoring (Obviously, my mistake) posts which haven't had any votes(meaning 0 votes) because of my `ORDER BY p.upvotes DESC` and as a result of this, i noticed that it fetched the first post in the table in the first 20 results, so the minimum timestamp becomes first post's timestamp. Now after this, if i try to fetch the next 20 results which is less than the minimum timestamp, it doesn't give anything.

Right now, i am simply using the upvotes ordering to fetch top records. Should i be using some algorithm like Bayesian Average or some other algorithm?

Please advise how i can improve the queries if i had to stay with current system of ordering or is there any viable and more efficient method i should be using?

P.S. If possible, please refer some resources about the Bayesian Average(it seems to be most used) or some other alternative?

Comment: Your first query should not ignore post with 0 upvotes, but start showing all post including the one with 0 upvotes, starting with the one that have greatest upvotes. In case all have upvotes 0 it will order them by the timestamp. Do I miss something? P.S. You should store the reached upvotes value too in a hidden field and pass it to the second query.

Comment: I am not fetching all posts matching the searched keyword in one go, i'm doing it in a lot of 20. So, it ignores the ones with 0 upvotes in the first query itself and one case where the one with minimum timestamp out of the first lot of 20 turned out to be the first post in the table due to which there was nothing to find in second query.

Comment: Your query has nothing in to suggest it would ignore 0 upvotes. The query you provided would show them

Comment: Also, sorting on a variable column like UPVOTES when you are retrieving the results in batches will result in unexpected bahaviour. What if the upvotes change between running the first batch and the second batch? You could get duplicate or missing results.

Comment: That does not help if the vote count changes between two batches.

Comment: The only way it ignores those with zero votes is if there are 20 or more records matching which have more than zero votes. Also note that using a leading wildcard in your LIKE will mean it ignores the indexes and will be slow.

Comment: As it is a bad way of sorting that i am using with problems like missing results due to change in votes during fetching, do you guys i think i should use a proper rating system while fetching the records? like something given [Here](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html)

Comment: Can not you just load the first 20, then first 40 (when more are requested), then 60, etc. So you data is always up to date.

Comment: @YasenZhelev i think it is more appropriate to append more results to the list rather than refreshing it every time.

Comment: If you want the sorts to be consistent then possibly best to move the votes onto a different table, with one row per vote including a timestamp for that vote. Then you can only include votes that were in place when the user started browsing

Comment: @Kickstart i already have a table exactly like that, with the data that you just suggested. Actually, i have the total number of votes in posts table and the individual votes with timestamps and post ids in another table. how do i use them exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the timestamp when you first do a search and then using that for the next query you could use something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM posts p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) FROM post_ratings WHERE timestamp_rated <= $SomeTimeStoredBetweenPages GROUP BY post_id) pr ON p.id = pr.post_id 
WHERE p.post like '%test%' 
ORDER BY pr.post_ratings DESC, p.unix_timestamp 
DESC LIMIT ".(($PageNo - 1) * 20)." 20";
```

This is very much an example as I have no real idea of you table structures. Also not sure if you just have a row for each up vote, or whether there are down votes to take account of as well.

Comment: downvotes are there too and there are specific rows for upvotes as well as downvotes. the table structure is exactly like you suggested.

Comment: I suppose you're assuming i'm doing pagination thats why the variable `$pageNo` but i am just giving a link at the end to load more results. So how can i fit your query into my structure?

Comment: You could just add a check for whether the row is an upvote or a downvote as a WHERE clause within the subselect. By giving a link for 'more records' you are effectively doing pagination. Just add a variable to the end of that link as the page number (defaulting to 1).